# To access to joomla site trhough http://web.es without showing into the url bar the /joomla folder name

Tags: .htaccess-configuration, joomla-3.5

i have a website in joomla. I have this site hosted in a remote server. I have this joomla placed into a folder in the root public_html folder. I have activated the url rewriting Global Option in the Joomla Admin Panel. I access to the website through the http://web.es/joomla.

I would like to access to this site through http://web.es without '/joomla'. I have been setting both the root level .htaccess as the .htaccess placed into the /public_html/joomla/ folder

root level (/public_html/) (/) .htaccess file content:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?web.es$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/joomla/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /joomla/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?web.es$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/joomla/
RewriteRule ^/joomla/(.*) joomla/ [L]
```

/public_html/joomla .htaccess file content:

```
##
# @package    Joomla
# @copyright  Copyright (C) 2005 - 2016 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license    GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
##

##
# READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE!
#
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that disallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
##

## No directory listings
IndexIgnore *

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes

## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On

## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#
## End - Custom redirects

##
# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##

 RewriteBase /joomla/

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
```

How could it be reached?

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this but I believe you need to put the .htaccess file also in the root folder but overall it seems more commonly recommended to move your joomla directory to the root folder. 
Some hosts have places where you can also adjust where the domain points but I believe that it also just creates or edits an .htaccess in the root DIR.

Items found

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26793005/htaccess-rewrite-rules-to-hide-joomla-in-subdirectory-conflicting-with-multiple
- https://docs.joomla.org/Moving_the_site_among_directories/sub-directories
- https://www.ostraining.com/support-forum/joomla-support/joomla-website-in-a-subdirectory-htaccesstxt-file/

Comment: Agreed - don't put make a full site backup with akeeba backup (to be safe), then move everything up a level - you don't need the /Joomla/ folder.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this matter i did this:

1. From the Add-on hosting account cpanel we have registered our web.es for our associated name of domain that we have reserved (Through this action a new subdomain associated folder uder `/public_html/` folder will be created).
2. `/public_html/.htaccess` file content:

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www.)?web.es.maindomain.es$ [NC]

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?web.es.maindomain.es$ [NC]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web.es.maindomain.es/

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web.es.maindomain.es/$1

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?web.es.maindomain.es$ [NC]

   RewriteRule ^(/)?$ web.es.main.es/ [L]
3. We also can modify the joomla adminnistrator `.../tmp` and `.../log` folders via Global Options and the `.../tmp` and `.../log` lines of the `/public_html/web.es/configuration.php`
4. The `/public_html/web.es/.htaccess` joomla site file haven't been necessary to modifying it (From my point of view and for my particular case this file only should be modified from `/administrator/` config options